# imagemagick Crop Accuracy

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am using `-crop` with a geometry object to crop an image with success. However, it seems to only round to the near `0.5`.

Is there a way to force `imagemagick` to use greater accuracy, such as up to 5 decimal places?

If not, are there any other tools that can help me achieve this via the command line?

Comment: I do not know if you can achieve 5 decimal places, but you can use -distort SRT 0 with viewport cropping to achieve fractional pixel cropping. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#distort_viewport and http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#srt. The viewport arguments for offset can be fractional pixel shifts. You can also add -precision X, but I am not sure if that helps in this situation.

Comment: How would you even know if you had 5 decimal places of accuracy?